# Necessary to delete dynamic struct contents, and then the struct itself?

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Product {
   char *     name;
   float      price;
};

int main() {
    Product * bread = new Product;
    bread->name = new char[6];
    bread->name = "bread";

    delete[] bread->name; //!!!THE ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE!!!
    delete bread;
}
```

Gives me the following error:

```
*** Error in `./out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400824 ***
```

My question is whether or not it's even necessary to delete bread->name, or if deleting bread will take care of that for me. If it is necessary to delete bread->name, why does the program crash when I try to do that?

Comment: Just FYI: I am only using char arrays because the professor of this class does not allow us to use strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue actually stems from here:

```
bread->name = "bread";
```

After allocating a new array for `name`, you are assigning that pointer to a completely different value - one that happens to live in read-only memory. Hence the error when you delete it: you're trying to `delete []` an array that you didn't allocate.

The key issue is that you don't want to assign the *pointer* `name`, you want to populate the contents of the array you just allocated - you want to populate what `name` *points to*. For that, [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy):

```
strcpy(bread->name, "bread");
```

Or really, since this is C++:

```
struct Product {
   std::string  name;
   float        price;
};

Product bread;
bread.name = "bread";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int main() {
    Product * bread = new Product;
    bread->name = new char[6];
    bread->name = "bread"; // <- Error! Overwriting the pointer value!

    delete[] bread->name; // <- Error! Trying to free read-only memory where "bread" is stored...
    delete bread;
}
```

Basically you're overwriting your dynamically allocated char array `new char[6]` with a constant char array of `"bread"`. Remove the dynamic allocation and you won't have to delete it.

When you write `"bread"` the compiler takes the letters and stores them in read-only memory. Every time you write `"bread"` and try and assign it you are effectively assigning a pointer to read-only memory, or a `const char*`.

When you allocated your dynamic array you stored the address of the dynamically allocated memory in the `bread->name` pointer but then you overwrote it with the address of the read-only memory which you are **not allowed to free**. Hence the compiler is complaining about it.

In your code since you no longer have the pointer to the dynamically allocated memory, `new char[6]`, you can no longer free it and you also have a memory leak.

I would do it like this (given your constraints on using strings) and assuming you really want the dynamic allocation:

```
int main() {
    const char* breadStr = "bread";
    int len = strlen(breadStr);

    Product * bread = new Product;
    bread->name = new char[len + 1];
    strncpy(bread->name, breadStr, len + 1); // Copy the string and the \0 (hence the +1)

    delete[] bread->name; // no more error!
    delete bread;
}
```

If dynamic allocation is *not required* then you could do something like this:

```
int main() {
    Product * bread = new Product;
    bread->name = "bread";

    // You don't have to delete the bread->name since it is NOT dynamically allocated but is in your read-only memory.
    delete bread;
}
```

But I would really prefer to do all of this in C++ using strings like @Barry suggested.

Comment: "But I would really prefer to do all of this in C++ using strings like @Barry suggested."

ME TOO! Thanks for your help!